# Implement a button or a toggle, when clicking, the action will be active for 3-5 seconds and STOP (using JS, HTML, CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, toggle

I need to display buttons or toggles for a feature, when selecting by a user, the action/function will be on for 3-5 seconds, and the action will stop without any user interaction (in CSS, HTML, JS). Any idea or thoughts...

I have toggles implemented, but I was wondering how I would put a timer on the action. When selected by the user, the action would stay on 3-5 seconds and stop without user interaction.

Comment: Please show us the releva;nt code so far. And what sort of 'action' are you talking of - would it be a CSS animation? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with putting code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but generally for delays in Javascript you can use the `setTimeout()` function.

```
function disableFeature() {
    // put code to disable feature here
}

function enableFeature() {
    // put code to enable/toggle feature here
    setTimeout(disableFeature, 5000);
}
```

You can read the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) of this function for more information.